# How to prevent the windows from sticking to the rubber seal?

Tags: window

When I lower down the windows of my car, I hear that the seal is a little stuck to it and I think that's going to damage it eventually.

What would be the way to prevent this? Is there some product I could apply to the rubber seal?

Note that this is happening in hot weather (so it's not due to the windows being frozen)

Comment: Dry lithium plus u can get it in an old dead cell phone battery

Answer (score 2):

If the interference is mild it may be useful to apply silicone spray to the rubber seal. As with any lubricant though, the effect will not last long.

The permanent fix is to address the cause for the interference. More likely than not the issue will be caused by a slight misalignment of the window regulator. Old rubber seals are unlikely to cause the window glass to stick as they tend to harden with time.

Comment: Also if its only catching on one side, one of the plastic clips on the bottom may have broke. Check the door panel for screws. If there's no acrews it will unclip bit make sure to lift because the plastic hangs over into the window frame and is normally briytle . speaker wires may not un clip besides the solderless connectora so try to lay it or twist it under the door. Don't forget to run the power window adapters before snapping the panel back on and it will save you from handling it too much.

Answer (score 2):

The old trick I knew was rubbing The seal with a dry bar of soap. Doesn't last forever but no worries of ruined clothes from touching it

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me with my 01 GC Laredo. I took black electrical tape and folded it over the flap along the whole window. Works great so far. Hasnt stuck since.!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Dupont Krytox (GPL-205).  It is expensive, but even a thin application to the rubber lasts a long time.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, I would first use a pipe cleaner to get out whatever gunk or adhesive is sticking to the window at the top. If it still occurs,get thin paper and put it in between the window and the bottom rubber area. If this paper sticks or has anything on it, I would go to drastic measures, like replacing the window, its motor (which may be where the sticky stuff is from (ie. the grease) and the rubber/plastic water seal from the inside and outide.